# Formatting x-axis labels in Kendo Charts for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-chart

[image]

I have specific requirements for the X-Axis Labels.

1. the last column should by styled differently (with a box in the background)
2. depending on the value - I might need to render a 2nd line (i.e. the year displayed beneath the month)
3. In addition, I'd like to add an icon to selected columns

The documentation lists 3 ways to format the labels - 'content', 'format' or 'create visual', I defined a 'visual' function

Below is a function which returns the label with an underline

[image]

```
xAxisLabelRenderer(e: AxisLabelVisualArgs) {
     const defaultLabel = e.createVisual(); const path = new Path({
 
     stroke: {
       color: 'red',
       width: 1,
       },
     });
 
     const bbox = defaultLabel.bbox();
     path.moveTo(bbox.bottomLeft()).lineTo(bbox.bottomRight());

     const group = new Group();
     group.append(defaultLabel, path);
 
     return group;   
   }
```

How do I make this look like my design? (no.1 above)